# Rails 3.2 - RSpec - Undefined method error while running RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, null

I'm writing some RSpec tests for a Rails 3.2 app, and Rspec keeps crashing on this test:

```
describe Person do
  before { @person = Person.new(names: [Factory.create(:name)], DOB: Date.today) }
  subject { @person }

  [:names,:DOB,:phone,:email,:address1,:address2,
  :city,:state,:zip,:notes,:last_seen].each do |value|
    it { should respond_to(value) }
  end

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when no name is present" do
    @person.names = []
    it {should be_invalid}
  end

  describe "when no DOB is present" do
    @person.DOB = nil
    it {should be_invalid}
  end
end
```

When I run RSpec, I get `undefined method 'names=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` for this line:
`@person.names = []`

If I remove the no-name test, then it crashs on `@person.DOB = nil`

It looks like somehow, `@person` isn't being set before the `describe` block. Is there some quirk of RSpec I'm missing?

**Edit:** The Person model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :names
  validates_presence_of :DOB
end
```

Pretty simple. There's a `names_people` join table to connect Name and Person. Like I've said, I can usually access name through `names=()`. It's something about this one test.

Comment: Shouldn't the `Person.new` be `Person.new(:names => [Factory.create(:name)], :DOB => Date.today)`?

Comment: make sure you've run `rake db:test:prepare` -- that gets me sometimes when active-record can't find the columns on the test db after a migration.

Comment: Hi, can you please give us more information about the Person model? It seems there is no accessor for the names attribute so the method names=() is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had to use the `before` method again to make changes to `@person`. For example, I had to use this:

```
describe "when no name is present" do
  before { @person.names = [] }
  it {should be_invalid}
end
```

Instead of this:

```
describe "when no name is present" do
  @person.names = []
  it {should be_invalid}
end
```